# Webhook to Google Sheet - Want to replace not append rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fairly new to App Script but I have searched the similar questions and I don't see a clear answer.  I hope someone can help me out here.

I develop IOT solutions for parks / recreation spaces and use the Particle platform.  I followed this Particle App note to have each of my devices send a snapshot of their configuration each morning so I can easily see the state of the fleet even when the devices are asleep / disconnected.

https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/app-notes/an011-publish-to-google-sheets/

I modified this example and it works well except for one thing:  I would like to append a new row to the sheet if it is a new device but to replace the existing row if the device had connected previously.  This way, the sheet reflects the current state of the fleet and does not continuously grow in length (as it does now).

Here is the relevant code from my current script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  // e.parameter.event
  // e.parameter.data
  // e.parameter.coreid
  // e.parameter.published_at "2016-04-16T13:37:08.728Z"

  var particleApiToken = '{{API Token Here}}';

  var publishedAt = new Date(e.parameter.published_at);
  var cacheKey = 'deviceName';

  var dataArray = [];
  try {
    dataArray = JSON.parse(e.parameter.data);
  }
  catch(e) {
  }
  
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var deviceNameCache = cache.get(cacheKey);
  
  if (!deviceNameCache) {
    // The device name was not cached, so use the Particle Cloud API
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices?access_token=' + particleApiToken);   
    var resultJson = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
    
    deviceNameCache = {};

    for(var ii = 0; ii < resultJson.length; ii++) {
      deviceNameCache[resultJson[ii].id] = resultJson[ii].name;
    }
    cache.put(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(deviceNameCache));
  }
  else {
    deviceNameCache = JSON.parse(deviceNameCache);
  }
  
  // Use the device name if known, otherwise use Device ID
  var deviceName = deviceNameCache[e.parameter.coreid];
  if (!deviceName) {
    Logger.log('Unknown device ID');
    return;
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var row = [e.parameter.coreid, deviceName, publishedAt];

  row = row.concat(dataArray);

  sheet.appendRow(row);

  var result = {};
  result.ok = true;

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Chip

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* IF EXISTING */
const r = 5; // load r of the device
sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

/* IF NEW */
// get the row of current device and store it
const r = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
sheet.appendRow(row);
/* store r */
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  I can see how this could come together and I will start working to integrate this into my code replacing the - 
sheet.appendRow(row); - line with this new code.  I have two (likely stupid) questions:
1) In your example, you assign the row number r a value if existing, how do I determine r?  
2) Likely related, each call that comes in won't know if it is "existing" how best to determine this?
I assume these can be connected with some look up in the sheet returning either the row or a null.  Any hints on how best to do this?  Thanks, Chip

Comment: 1) `r` is obtained in the line `const r =...`, you may store it together with `cacheKey`. I am not familiar with `CacheService`. 2) You are adopting `CacheService` to determine this, aren't you?

Comment: I see what you are suggesting and it is a solid solution as it simply stores the row in the spreadsheet in the cache.  I need to think about how to make this work as I am not an expert and am attempting to adapt an example provided in the original post.

I would think there would be another way to do this by searching for the row in the active sheet that has a device ID of the new device.  If found, we would have "r" and if not found, we could use the sheet.getLastRow() + 1 or sheet.appendRow(row) method.   Make Sense?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to check existence from the sheet which I think may not be efficient. Maybe it is better to `setProperty(device, r)` with [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperty(String,String)) because it is object-like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great advice from user @idfurw, I was able to modify the code to either overwrite existing entries or replace them if they exist.  The appendRow line in my original post was replaced with this code:

```
  // This is the new section that determines if a row should be appended or overwritten
  // Row numbers are printed in the last column for testing and will be removed
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();           // Store properties in the document
  var rowIndex = documentProperties.getProperty(e.parameter.coreid);            // Index will tbe the deviceID

  if (!rowIndex) {                            // Row information not found - new row needed
    rowIndex = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;        // Get the last row number
    documentProperties.setProperty(e.parameter.coreid, rowIndex);    // Store the row number in the properties for next time
    row = row.concat(rowIndex);               // Concatenate the row number - for testing - to be removed
    sheet.appendRow(row);                     // Add this row to the end of the sheet
    Logger.log('New Entry - Appended');
  }
  else {
    row = row.concat(rowIndex);               // Concatenate the row number - for testing - to be removed
    sheet.getRange(Math.floor(rowIndex), 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);    // Overwrite the row
    Logger.log('Existing Entry - Overwritten');
  }
```

Thank you again for your help and I hope someone else can benefit from this approach - or suggest a better one!

Chip

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer above almost worked!  There was just one problem, sometimes two devices would publish their web hooks at the same second.  They would both spin up a thread and would both get assigned the same row number.  This is OK the first day as they would not overwrite each other until the next day.

Thinking I knew what I was doing, I created this function and scheduled it to run before midnight each day.  This seemed to work when I tested it (duplicate row numbers were eliminated) but the next day, the devices ignored these document properties and simply appended themselves to the sheet.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here but it seems that this document properties approach will not work.  May need to go to the inefficient method of looking up each entry as it comes in.  Input / advice welcome.

Here is the code I tried:

```
function resetRowProperties() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  documentProperties.deleteAllProperties();


  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log('Cleared All Document Properties');
  for (var rowIndex = 2; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRow(); rowIndex++) {
    documentProperties.setProperty(range.getCell(rowIndex,1), rowIndex);    // Store the row number in the properties for next time
    var cell = sheet.getRange(rowIndex,13);
    cell.setValue(rowIndex);
  }
  Logger.log('Reset Row Properties for the Sheet');
}
```

Thanks, Chip